# Computing $\lim_{x\to-1}\frac{2x+\sqrt{3-x}}{x^2+x}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits

I have this limit as my question to solve:

$$\lim_{x\to-1}\frac{2x+\sqrt{3-x}}{x^2+x}$$

My procedure:

$$\lim_{x\to-1}\frac{(2x+\sqrt{3-x})(2x-\sqrt{3-x})}{(x^2+x)(2x-\sqrt{3-x})}$$

$$\lim_{x\to-1}\frac{4x^2+x-3}{(x^2+x)(2x-\sqrt{3-x})}$$

$$\lim_{x\to-1}\frac{(x+1)(x-\frac{3}{4})}{x(x+1)(2x-\sqrt{3-x})}$$

$(x+1)$ is the zero factor and has to be eliminated.

$$\frac{-1-\frac{3}{4}}{-1(2(-1)-\sqrt{3-(-1)})}=-\frac{7}{16}$$

But when I checked my answer, I found it's wrong and the right answer is $-\frac{7}{4}$.

What was my mistake here?

Comment: $4x^2+x-3\ne(x+1)(x-\frac34)$. The coefficients of $x^2$ do not match.

Comment: I don't know why my question is down-voted. Isn't it a good question when you share your way of solving to others so that they can tell you your mistakes? I always thought it's a bad question when you ask others to solve a question for you without your own effort. If it's considered a bad question please don't show your homework to your teacher anymore!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because $\displaystyle4x^2+x-3=(x+1)(4x-3)$ rather than $\displaystyle(x+1)\left(x-\frac34\right)$.

Comment: Thank you so much. Since $a+c=b$ in my question, ($ax^2+bx+c$), I suddenly thought it is like when the quadratic equals to zero; and a solution is $-1$ and the other $-\frac{c}{a}$

Comment: The general rule is: if the roots of $ax^2+bx+c$ (with $a\ne0$) are $\alpha$ and $\beta$, then$$ax^2+bx+c=a(x-\alpha)(x-\beta).$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Your factorisation is not correct.

It is easier to do it if you let $t=\sqrt{3-x}$, then $x= 3-t^2$ and $t\to 2$.